# Getting UTF-8 Request Parameter Strings in mod_perl2

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, apache2, mod-perl

I'm using mod_perl2 for a website and use CGI::Apache2::Wrapper to get the request parameters for the page (e.g. post data).  I've noticed that the string the $req->param("parameter") function returns is not UTF-8.  If I use the string as-is I can end up with garbled results, so I need to decode it using Encode::decode_utf8().  Is there anyway to either get the parameters already decoded into UTF-8 strings or loop through the parameters and safely decode them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the parameters already decoded, we would need to override the behaviour of the underlying class `Apache2::Request` from **libapreq2**, thus losing its XS speed advantage. But that is not even straightforward possible, as unfortunately we are sabotaged by the `CGI::Apache2::Wrapper` constructor:

```
unless (defined $r and ref($r) and ref($r) eq 'Apache2::RequestRec') {
```

This is wrong OO programming, it should say

```
… $r->isa('Apache2::RequestRec')
```

or perhaps forego class names altogether and just test for behaviour (`… $r->can('param')`).

I say, with those obstacles, it's not worth it. I recommend to **keep your existing solution that decodes parameters explicitly.** It's clear enough.

To loop over the request parameters, simply do not pass an argument to the `param` method and you get a list of the names. This is documented ([1](http://p3rl.org/CGI%3a%3aApache2%3a%3aWrapper#Apache2%3a%3aRequest), [2](http://p3rl.org/Apache2%3a%3aRequest#param)), please read more carefully.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much confirmed what I was afraid of.  My initial thought was to use the $req->param() to get the table and loop through the parameters there.  I could get the table object for the parameters, but when I tried to set any parameter, it errored out saying STORE wasn't implemented.